# Function declared in object is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I have an object with a method inside called `Handler.addToScore()`. When this method is called I am getting an error saying that it is not a function. I don't know what can be wrong here.

```
const DOM = () => {
  const dom = {}

  dom.score = document.getElementsByClassName('score')[0]

  return dom
}

const State = () => {
  const state = {}

  state.score = 0
  state.isLoggedIn.facebook = 0
  state.isLoggedIn.linkedin = 0

  return state
}

const Handler = () => {
  const handler = {}

  handler.addToScore = function() { DOM.score.innerHTML = State.score }
  return handler
}

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  if(response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log( 'Logged in and authenticated' )
    Handler.addToScore()
  } else {
    console.log('Not authenticated')
  }
}
```

Comment: well Handler is a function so it does not have the method until you execute it...

Comment: `Handler` is a function that returns an object with a method. It doesn't have that method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run the function Handler before calling addToScore method

```
Handler().addToScore();
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the line to

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  if (response.status === "connected") {
    console.log("Logged in and authenticated");
    Handler().addToScore(); // see comment, Handler is a function. 
  } else {
    console.log("Not authenticated");
  }
}
```